# How to collect values into an array and pass the collection to datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am working on a custom POS application in Asp.Net using C# where I have two DataGridViews on a windows form. The DataGridView1 is showing all sales. When a user clicks on any record in DataGridView1, certain details like ProductName, Quantity, Variation, UnitPrice and TotalCost from the selected record on DataGridView is passed to the DataGridView2. This is done using the CurrentCellChanged event in DataGridView2.

My problem is that I have more than one details related to each sale which I am trying to show on DataGridView2 but I can't set each detail of a selected sale as the DataSource for DataGridView2. Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
private void DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string saleId = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        DataGridView2.DataSource = SalesClass.SelectedSaleDetails(saleId);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Here, the CurrentCellChanged event pass the selected SaleId to my SalesClass where I am querying  sales details related to this specific SaleId, like this:

```
public static DataTable SelectedSaleDetails(string saleId)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = DataAccess.Select(string.Format("select * from vSalesDetails where SaleID = {0}", saleId));
    string[] values;

    foreach (DataRow drItem in dt.Rows)
    {
        string variation = drItem["ProductVariation"].ToString();


        string productName = drItem["ProductName"].ToString();
        decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(drItem["SaleQuantity"]);
        decimal saleCostLevelC = Convert.ToDecimal(drItem["LevelCCost"]);
        decimal purchaseCostLevelC = Convert.ToDecimal(drItem["LevelCPurchaseCost"]);
        decimal levelBStandard = Convert.ToDecimal(drItem["LevelBStandard"]);
        decimal levelCStandard = Convert.ToDecimal(drItem["LevelCStandard"]);

        decimal parentTotalSalesCost = 0;
        decimal levelATotalSalesCost = 0;
        decimal levelBTotalSalesCost = 0;
        decimal levelCTotalSalesCost = 0;
        decimal salecost = 0;
        decimal unitCost = 0;
        switch (variation)
        {
            case "Parent Product":
                decimal soleProductUnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(drItem["SoleProductUnitPrice"]);

                salecost = quantity * soleProductUnitPrice;
                unitCost = soleProductUnitPrice;
                break;

            case "Level A":
                decimal levelBSaleCost = levelCStandard * saleCostLevelC;
                decimal levelASaleCost = levelBStandard * levelBSaleCost;

                salecost = quantity * levelASaleCost;
                unitCost = levelASaleCost;
                break;

            case "Level B":
                decimal saleCostLevelB = levelCStandard * saleCostLevelC;
                salecost = quantity * saleCostLevelB;
                unitCost = saleCostLevelB;
                break;

            case "Level C":
                salecost = quantity * saleCostLevelC;
                unitCost = saleCostLevelC;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        values = new string[] {productName, variation, unitCost.ToString(), quantity.ToString(), salecost.ToString()};
    }

//  return each of the productName, variation, unitCost and quantity of a selected Sale here. This is going to be assigned as the DataGridView2 DataSource.
}
```

My code is working fine and I am able to get all the required values in `values` array within the foreach loop. However, I am somehow not able to pass sale details (productName, variation, unitCost and quantity) of a specific sale back to the DataGridView2 DataSource here:

```
DataGridView2.DataSource = //values returned from SalesClass;
```

Is there anyone who can suggest me a better yet efficient approach for this as I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reassigning `values` as the last line in the `foreach` loop. So, when you exit that loop `values` is only going to have the data for the last row in `dt`.

Why not create a second `DataTable`, massage the data from `dt` into the second `DataTable` and just return that?

```csharp
public static DataTable SelectedSaleDetails(string saleId)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = DataAccess.Select(string.Format("select * from vSalesDetails where SaleID = {0}", saleId));

    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    result.Columns.Add("ProductName");
    result.Columns.Add("Variation");
    result.Columns.Add("UnitCost");
    result.Columns.Add("Quantity");
    result.Columns.Add("SaleCost");

    foreach (DataRow drItem in dt.Rows)
    {
       // Massage the data like you're doing...
       // And replace the assignment to values with...

       var row = result.NewRow();
       row["ProductName"] = productName;
       row["Variation"] = variation;
       row["UnitCost"] = unitCost.ToString();
       row["Quanity"] = quantity.ToString();
       row["SaleCost"] = saleCost.ToString();
       result.Add(row);
    }
    return result;
}
```

On a side note, you probably want to see about changing `DataAccess.Select` to handle parameterized queries. As it is now, you might have a [SQL Injection Vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: it worked for me. Thanks for the free tip of pointing out this major SQL Injection Vulnerability. Will better have to go with a reliable solution for this as well. Thanks again for your polite suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the documentation for [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.8)? It looks like you need to declare a `BindingSource` along side your declaration of `DataGridView1` and `DataGridView2`.

```
private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
```

Then change your code to

```
string saleId = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
bindingSource1.DataSource = SalesClass.SelectedSaleDetails(saleId);   
DataGridView2.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Don't return a `string[]` type from `SalesClass.SelectedSaleDetails`. You want to return your `DataTable` `dt`.